# Password in HTML editable, although "contenteditable=false"?

Tags: html, input, passwords, contenteditable

I have a simple input field with a given value just as the following:

```
<input class="pw" contenteditable="false" type="password" value="1234"></input>
```

As you can see, I set "contenteditable" to "false" meaning that I shouldn't be able to change the value from the Browser.
However, I can change it and I have no idea why?

Comment: make it disabled=”disabled”. contenteditable is a special property that allows a user to edit an element’s content to some extent, which is not the same as its value

Comment: Doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Dear if you want to show password in non-editable input field then you shoud use read only attribute.

```
<input class="pw" type="password" value="1234" readonly="true"></input>
```

Comment: Jeez, how did I miss that.. Thank you